# How to get the pointer position of beginning of second line using TFileStream in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pointers

I'm trying to create a list of pointers to store pointers of beginning of each line using TFileStream in Delphi.
I have gone through the following link [TFileStream_Methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TFileStream_Methods) to check all the methods. but i didn't find anything useful using which i can find the pointer value of starting position of each line.

I have tried following :

```
procedure TForm4.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  InStream: TFileStream;
  OutStream: TMemoryStream;
  Writer: TStreamWriter;
  Buffer: TArray<Byte>;
  Encoding: TEncoding;
  BOMValue: Integer;
  FileName: string;
  Temp: string;
  TempInt: Integer;
  //Buffer2: Buffer;
begin
  try
    //SetLength(Buffer, 8);
    //InStream.Read(Buffer, Length(Buffer));
  finally
    //InStream.Free;
  end;

  try
    SetLength(Buffer, 8);
    //InStream.Read(Buffer, Length(Buffer));
  finally
    //InStream.Free;
  end;

  Encoding := nil;
  BOMValue := TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(Buffer, Encoding, TEncoding.ASCII);

  OutStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Writer := TStreamWriter.Create(OutStream, Encoding);
  FileName := 'C:\bugs\Rnd\mainfile.cpp';
  try
    InStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
    InStream.Seek(BOMValue, soCurrent);

    Temp := InStream.ToString();
    TempInt := InStream.InstanceSize();
    OutStream.CopyFrom(InStream, 10);
    InStream.Seek(10, soCurrent);
    Writer.Write('abc');

    OutStream.CopyFrom(InStream,60);

    InStream.Free;

    OutStream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    //InStream.Free;
    Writer.Free;
    OutStream.Free;
  end;

end;
```

I am having the `InStream`, how can I read it character by character (even multibyte character) and can calculate the pointer of the first position of each line.

I have been trying for past 2 days but didn't have any luck. Any help would he highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to scan through the file character by character, respecting the text encoding. Not the easiest of tasks. Why do you want to do it at all? Perhaps there's a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi David, Suppose I want to rename a word at line 20th and column 34, then then i will just get the pointer of 20th line and move to 34th offset and will rename. that's why i want to store the pointer. Which is the better approach if you can tell me it would be very helpful.

Comment: What do you know about the file? Are all the lines the same length? If not then you need to walk through the entire file to find the 20th line.

Comment: Yes, to create the list of pointers of beginning of each line. I will be reading the entire file for the first time. the problem is that am having TFileStream and I want to create that list of pointers from that TFileStream. Can you give me some idea how can i do.

Comment: My first comment tells you what you need to do. Why not try?

Comment: I understand offset and pointers are different. if we scan through the file character by character, we will get the offset of each line starting point. while i want pointer of that position

Comment: As you scan through the file, whenever you read, the stream's `Position` property tells you the location of the file pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) will try.

Comment: Your approach can only work if the renamed word has the same length (with respect to the encoding) as the original word.

Comment: Are your output file's size lower than say a 100 mb?. If so why you do not use meta data like approach, where you store the position of the lines (respecting the encoding of course) the first time you write the file. And when loading the file try to load the hall file so you could edit the words (taking Uwe Raabe's comment into account).